# Split string by symbol that is not between specific symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string by "&" only in cases when "&" is not between "<%" and "%>" symbols. Between that symbols i have special expressions that i want to ignore during the split. Text is considered as special only when it is between two closest "<%" text "%>".
It works like this:

```
<%qwr<%qrw<%tret%>wet%>qwt => only this is scpecial <%tret%>
<%test142%>wqr%>%<%%>qwr%> => only this is <%test142%> and <%%> is special
```

Examples:

```
1) my&string=21<%253&124%> <&> && => ['my', 'string=21<%253&124%> <', '> ', '', '']

2) new<%<&%235<%test&gg%>&test&f => ['new<%<', '%235<%test&gg%>', 'test', 'f']

3) a&<%&qwer&>ty%>&af => ['a', '<%&qwer&>ty%>', 'af']
```

I tried `'\&(?![^<%]*%>)'` and `(?<!(<%))\&(?!(%>))` but that works wrong.

Comment: I suggest writing a parser for it. `s.match(/(?:(?!<%(?:(?!<%|%>).)*%>)[^&]|<%(?:(?!<%|%>).)*%>)+/g)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQo9cB/1/)) will not extract empty matches and if you replace `+` with `*` at the end, you will get too many empty matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a workaround.

1. match all `<% & %>` and replace it with a special char (in my case `_` underscore) so the result is `<% _ %>`
2. now split the string with `&` char
3. finaly replace the special char `_` back to `&`

```js
const mySplit = (mystr) => {
  const regex = /<%(?!%>).*%>/gm;
  const matches = mystr.match(regex);

  const tmpreplace = matches.map(e => e.replace(/&/g,'_'));
  matches.forEach(e => mystr = mystr.replace(e,tmpreplace));

  return mystr.split('&').map(e => e.replace(/_/g,'&'));
}

console.log(mySplit('my&string=21<%253&124%> <&> &&'));
console.log(mySplit('new<%<&%235<%test&gg%>&test&f'));
console.log(mySplit('a&<%&qwer&>ty%>&af'));
```

Comment: What if there will be user's "_" or any other special character? For example, we decided to replace "&" with "___mysupersecretsymbol___". User can eter this string by his own

Comment: You can use **"_mysupersecretsymbol"** or something similar to prevent, that the users using the same. It's not 100% safe.

The regex is the second Problem. Some strings are to complex to match always right. 

Best solution would be a own parser (see comment from @Wiktor Stribiżew
), but that's outside from my personal knowledge.